# What is the differences between the two ways of passing compare argument when using sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, parameter-passing

I found there are two ways to use sort() in c++.
one way is to write the compare function before sort().

```
const static bool comp(vector<int>a, vector<int>b){
    return a[0]<b[0] || (a[0]==b[0] && a[1]>b[1]);
}

sort(num.begin(),num.end(),comp);
```

another way is to write as follows:

```
sort(num.begin(),num.end(),[](const auto& a, const auto& b){
    return a[0]<b[0] || (a[0]==b[0] && a[1]>b[1]);
});
```

when I was solving leetcode354, I got a timeout using the first method but passed with the second method.
So what are the differences here? why the second method runs dramatically faster than the first one?

Comment: you're comparing apples and oranges here: the prototype of the first necessitates a copy of the array elements, while the second takes a reference. you should get a good C++ book instead of trying to learn it from the ground up by emulating leetcode answers.

Comment: frankly, this question is a symptom of trying to learn from competition sites and using code you found somewhere without actually understanding what it does. You should rather learn from proper lectures and/or books. Any decent introduction to C++ should explain the difference between passing by value vs passing by reference in the first chapters

Comment: *when I was solving leetcode354* -- That's your first mistake, and that is using leetcode as a C++ learning tool.  The questions asked on leetcode assume you are an *experienced* programmer who wants to spend some spare time answering random puzzle questions.  If you are not aware of passing by value versus passing by reference (a basic fundamental of C++), then you are not ready to use C++ as the language in answering leetcode questions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably get a timeout with this

```
sort(num.begin(),num.end(),[](auto a,auto b){
    return a[0]<b[0] || (a[0]==b[0] && a[1]>b[1]);
});
```

And no timeout with this comparator:

```
const static bool comp(const vector<int>&a, const vector<int>& b){
    return a[0]<b[0] || (a[0]==b[0] && a[1]>b[1]);
}
```

The main difference is that one passes the parameters by value, ie the vectors are copied on each single comparison, while the other passes them by reference.

Do not make copies of large objects when you do not need a copy.